# I deposited money in my paypal on march 9th and I hasn't arrived yet. What do I do?

Tags: paypal

I have deposited some money on my PayPal Account from my Bank on march 9 th and I haven't received a confirmation yet. What are my options? I have already contacted customer service on march 15th and I have not received an answer. So what should I do now?

Comment: Contact customer service again.

Comment: If they don't respond, how long should I wait inbetween?

Comment: Has the money been removed from your account? If so, I don't think e-mailing *daily* would be inappropriate.

Comment: alright,thanks it has